# Open PDF in WebView with generate Url

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I created a small application with a webview of my website.
I have a problem, indeed I have order forms in pdf, I want to open or download them in the webview but it does not work, nothing happens.
Do you have a solution?

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("pdf.php")) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WebView` does not support PDF directly. Your choices are:

- Convert your PDF order forms to Web pages
- Convert your PDF order forms to native Android user interfaces
- Use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)
- Allow the user to view the form in a regular PDF viewer on Android (e.g., `PdfRenderer`, [`AndroidPdfViewer`](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer))
- Embed some other non-`WebView` PDF viewer in your app
- Use an undocumented, unsupported, and potentially unreliable Google Docs URL to render your PDFs

[This blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) describes the latter four options. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/PDF) contains sample projects showing the PDF.js and "other non-`WebView` PDF viewer" options.